# Microsoft Power BI: Line chart last 13 weeks data for 3 years

Tags: powerbi

I need to show line chart visual for last 13 years data for 2017,2018 and 2018. Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

[image]
I have a table called Profit 
columns : Profit, WeekEndingDate, Year

I tried to create last 13 weeks measure but only showed 7 weeks as we are only 7 weeks in 2019 and also only showed data for 2018 and 2019.

I need to display each year individually with 13 weeks data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are linked to dates.

You can use the visual filters to show a date range from today and step back 3 months

Edit:

could you post the measure you created to get the last 13 weeks, it needs to be edited to ignore year. that should do the trick

Comment: I have the date table linked and the date slicer gives data for last 13 weeks from current date. I need to show data for last 13 weeks of individual 3 years as in the picture I posted.

Comment: last 13 weeks from current week = 
 var today=TODAY() 
     var currentweek=WEEKNUM(today,1) 
          return IF(MAX([weeknum])<=currentweek&&MAX([weeknum])>currentweek-13,1,0)